# Encrypted Password in xmlp-server-config.xml

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

I have a problem: when i go to BI Publisher, my admin tab didn't appear.
Then when I go to `\OracleBI\xmlp\XMLP\Admin\Configuration\xmlp-server-config.xml`.
I have no encrypted password in BI_USER_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD_ENC as I have read in tutorial in internet.  Where is the encrypted password stored?

Hope you can help me solve this.

Thanks

Comment: My Point is how to activate the admin's tab in BI publisher(i run it in localhost), i suppose there is some problem in \OracleBI\xmlp\XMLP\Admin\Configuration\xmlp-server-config.xml but not sure, do you have any suggest?

Comment: What "internet tutorial" are you following?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the Admin tab ought to appear.  Try following the admin in Venkatakrishnan J's blog article: [Oracle BI Publisher and BI EE – Invisible Admin Tab!!](http://oraclebizint.wordpress.com/2007/11/06/oracle-bi-publisher-and-bi-ee-invisible-admin-tab/)

Comment: Thank so much, i already solved it with applying the obiee user group in bi admin tools